# How do I get child elements from class list object?

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, css

think I have some class of same content

```
 <div class="parentclass">

         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
    </div>

  <div class="parentclass">

         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
         <div class="childClass">
         </div>
    </div>
```

I can get all the parent class object in an array by

```
var pClassList= document.getElementsByClassName("parentclass");
```

My question is how can I access the child classes "childClass" from pClassList array calling it index like

```
var childClassList1= pClassList[0].getElementsByClassName("childClass");
var childClassList2= pClassList[1].getElementsByClassName("childClass");
```

Comment: hmm.. what does this have to do with html node.js or css3?

Answer (score 1):

Simply loop over the initial collection and use index of each iteration to access individual elements

```
var pClassList= document.getElementsByClassName("parentclass");

for(var i=0; i < pClassList.length; i++){

  var parentElement = pClassList[i];
  // do something to each parent as needed
  // access children of parent element
  var childClassList= parentElement.getElementsByClassName("childClass");
  // do something with `childClassList`
  for (var j= 0; j < childClassList.length; j++){
    var child = childClassList[j];
    // do something with each child here
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Could be:

```
var childClassList1= pClassList[0].getElementsByClassName("childClass")[0];
var childClassList2= pClassList[1].getElementsByClassName("childClass")[0];
```

I prefer to use JQuery, in this case it would be.

```
var pClassList = $(".parentclass")
var childClassList1 = $(pClassList[0]).children().first() 
var childClassList2 = $(pClassList[1]).children().first()
```

Answer (score 0):

The following will retrieve child nodes with classname="childClass" for the first element in pClassList array:

```
for (var i = 0; i < pClassList[0].childNodes.length; i++) {
if (pClassList[0].childNodes[i].className == "childClass") {
  //Do something with pClassList[0].childNodes[i]
}        
}
```

You can do the same for the rest of the elements in pClassList array by iterating over each of them.

Answer (score -1):

An alternative I think is you select as you want childClass is like :

```js
var childClassList1= document.querySelector('.childClass:nth-child(2)');
```

Comment: @NateAnderson Thanks !